# The right place to put "Workshop organizer & instructor" on resume or LinkedIn

Tags: resume, linkedin

I've organized two workshops for beginners about web development for young adults that do not attend CS university courses. These workshops were four months apart, each lasting only one day (6) hours and I was the main organizer and instructor.

I'm wondering how to include this experience on my LinkedIn profile or on my resume?

Comment: Do you have any other items on your resume or LinkedIn profile that aren't directly related to full time employment? ie clubs, professional organizations, volunteering, etc.? I ask because as much as I like @AffableAmbler's suggestions, I think it'll look strange to have a section with only one item listed. Might want to drum up some other things to put with it and make the section(s) more generic. I do think it is a good idea to show this off though, even if it was only two days, it displays your enthusiasm and organizational/leadership skills.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's particularly relevant to the job(s) you're applying for, I wouldn't bother using precious space on your resume for an experience that only lasted a total of two days.  If you do decide to include it, you could create a section called "Teaching Experience."

Because there's no space limit on LinkedIn, I would recommend listing it under the "Accomplishments" header.  You could of course add it under "Experience" but this is usually where recruiters look for your long-term work experience and it would probably look strange to see jobs that lasted only one day.